# Can Masonry use as RTL (Right-To-Left) direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry, right-to-left

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) worked fine with the text direction from LTR (Left-To-Right). Now I want to use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) with the text direction RTL (Right-To-Left [Middle eastern languages such as Hebrew and Arabic are written predominantly right-to-left.] ).

Whenever I run [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) on the [RTL (Right-To-Left)](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html)  text direction, the [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin setups all its grid layout in the LTR (Left-To-Right) format.

I also go through from the [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin's documentation but didn't find any setting related to [RTL (Right-To-Left)](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html)  direction.

Any proposed solution?

Comment: hint: have a look at the `isOriginLeft` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about two years late, but I had the same problem and found the solution provided by Masonry.

There is an option `isRTL` which arranges tiles from right to left:

```
$('.tile-view').masonry({ 
    columnWidth: 200,
    isRTL: true
});
```

Comment: As per the documentation of masonry, option originLeft arranges items from left to right:

`$('selctor').masonry({    
    originLeft: false
});`

Answer (score 16):

I think `isOriginLeft: false` is the right answer, according to [this](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html) site

Comment: ```isOriginLeft: false```,  this worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

You can float the items right in css:

```
.masonry .item {
  float: right;
}
```

then change the option `isOriginLeft: false` in your javascript.

Here is a little codepen to illustrate:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gkCiG

Comment: Well what a case of horrible documentation. This solution works, but the [officially documented solution "isRTL:true"](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/options.html#isrtl) does not work. in fact, that is nowhere in the [source code](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/masonry.js) at all.

Answer (score 4):

**[OriginLeft](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#originleft)**

Controls the horizontal flow of the layout. By default, item elements start positioning at the left, with originLeft: true. Set originLeft: false for right-to-left layouts.

```
originLeft: false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want right-to-left layout, especially when your content includes images; Like Bootstrap cards that may contain images. Then get help from this code snippet.

**Note**: You need two libraries, [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) and [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

```
//See docs: https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded
//See demo: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/MwJoLQ
var grid = document.querySelector('.masonry');
var msnry;

imagesLoaded(grid, function () {
    // init Isotope after all images have loaded
    msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
        // options
        percentPosition: true,
        originLeft: false
    });
});
```

Also, Considering the [removal of Masonry from Bootstrap 5](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#cards), the above may be a good guide for those friends.